# Detect the click event of the "Done" button (youtube video)

Tags: ios, swift, video, youtube

I have an UIViewController (in my swift application) containing a different elements between them a button. When the button is clicked a create an UIWebView, add it to the subView then a load  a youtube video inside it. When the video is fullscreen, I want to dismiss the webView when the "Done" button is clicked. I searched a lot but I didn't find what I'm looking for. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Redirect as in load a different web page? If you could clarify your issue that would help.

Comment: @dylan please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Is your done button on the web page?  If so you want to inject javascript code to your done button and cause it to initiate navigation when clicked by using [stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascript).  If you set yourself as the delegate of the UIWebview you can intercept the navigation request in the UIWebViewDelegate method [webView(_:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview).  Check if the URL matches what you expect and if so cancel the request and dismiss the webView.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I play the video a got the same player as showen [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mA13v.png) . Will your suggestion work in this case?

Comment: Can you give me please an example containing what you said in your answer? Because I don't really get how can I apply what you suggest.(Excuse me I'm really new to ios development) :)

Comment: it looks like UIWebView is using AVPlayer to play the youtube video.  In that case this is not going to work because thats a native control and not a HTML element.  In that case use google's youtube helper pod: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: I tried to use it but I was facing a big problem with the bridge-header that I have created: the swift compiler doesn't detect the bridge file and also the YTPlayerView .h. I losted a lot of time trying to figure it out but I didn't! I have a question please: what is the render of the youtube-ios-player-helper ? Is it similar to the youtube site? And also is there a button or something similar to leave the video? Thanks a  lot

Comment: I hope this would be helpful - https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/149